# Marker of the last visited link

Tags: html

**HTML5**

I'd like to somehow mark a visited link within the current page.
Links are opened in a new tab.

The life of the marker is supposed to be till the page is reloaded.

Reason: it is a huge list of links. A wall of links of similarly looking links. I need a marker. And css "visited" pseudo class seems to be unsuitable here: it shows whether the link was visited at all, not the last visited link.

This is what seemed suitable:

```
<div>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="group">
        <a href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank">https://www.example.com</a>
    </label>
</div>

<div>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="group">
        <a href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank">https://www.example.com</a>
    </label>
</div>
```

Two problems:

1. Radio button can be switched by clicking the marker itself rather
   than the link.
2. It doesn't work at all: the marker is not switched
       when I click a link.

Could you help me with this. If this is a complete garbage of in idea, maybe there is something more elegant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved like this:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="group" onclick="window.location='"https://www.example.com"';">
    https://www.example.com
</label>
```